# Pyspark dataframe column value dependent on value from another row

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like this:

```
columns = ['manufacturer', 'product_id']
data = [("Factory", "AE222"), ("Sub-Factory-1", "0"), ("Sub-Factory-2", "0"),("Factory", "AE333"), ("Sub-Factory-1", "0"), ("Sub-Factory-2", "0")]
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
df = rdd.toDF(columns)
 
+-------------+----------+
| manufacturer|product_id|
+-------------+----------+
|      Factory|     AE222|
|Sub-Factory-1|         0|
|Sub-Factory-2|         0|
|      Factory|     AE333|
|Sub-Factory-1|         0|
|Sub-Factory-2|         0|
+-------------+----------+
```

Which I want to turn into this:

```
+-------------+----------+
| manufacturer|product_id|
+-------------+----------+
|      Factory|     AE222|
|Sub-Factory-1|     AE222|
|Sub-Factory-2|     AE222|
|      Factory|     AE333|
|Sub-Factory-1|     AE333|
|Sub-Factory-2|     AE333|
+-------------+----------+
```

So that each `Sub-Factory` gets the value from the closest `Factory` Value above the current `Sub-Factory` row. I can solve it with a nested for loop but it is not very efficient since there could be millions of rows. I have looked into Pyspark Window function but cannot really wrap my head around it. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any column `type` to distinguish `Factory` from `sub-factory`? Or an `ID`?

Comment: Yes, both Factory and sub-factory-1 or sub-factory-2 are categorical. So Factory will always be just Factory not Factory-23343 and sub-factory will always be sub-factory-1 or sub-factory-2. Also order is guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `first` function with `ignorenulls=True` over a Window. But you need to identify groups of `manufacturer` in order to partition by that `group`.

As you didn't give any `ID` column I'm using `monotonically_increasing_id` and a cumulative conditional sum to create a group column:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "row_id",
    F.monotonically_increasing_id()
).withColumn(
    "group",
    F.sum(F.when(F.col("manufacturer") == "Factory", 1)).over(Window.orderBy("row_id"))
).withColumn(
    "product_id",
    F.when(
        F.col("product_id") == 0,
        F.first("product_id", ignorenulls=True).over(Window.partitionBy("group").orderBy("row_id"))
    ).otherwise(F.col("product_id"))
).drop("row_id", "group")

df1.show()
#+-------------+----------+
#| manufacturer|product_id|
#+-------------+----------+
#|      Factory|     AE222|
#|Sub-Factory-1|     AE222|
#|Sub-Factory-2|     AE222|
#|      Factory|     AE333|
#|Sub-Factory-1|     AE333|
#|Sub-Factory-2|     AE333|
#+-------------+----------+
```